# How Mobile device Simulation works?

Tags: android, testing, mobile

I have used perfectomobile and they provide actual mobile  devices simulation over Flash . I am wondering how they do it ?

They are doing it for both android and iPhone

Do they stream mobile  screen with data cable ? How touch is passed on to device ?

I can see they are real devices because they have a phone number and all other features .

Does any one have an idea ?

Comment: Emulating the device? I don't quite understand what you're asking...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about iOS and Win8 but Android is just a tiny distribution of Linux. Linux can host a VNC server. A device that hosts a VNC server can be controlled and viewed from remote. VNC (and/or remote desktop systems like VNC) are available for MacOS X and Windows systems, as well, so it is possible that this technique can be used on Apple and Microsoft portable devices as well.

Despite this, the HW/SW requirements of perfectomobile seems to be more video-streaming-depending:

```
Internet Browser (Explorer 7/8/9, Firefox latest, Chrome latest, Safari)
Adobe Flash 11.1 and above
Broadband Internet connection (at least 1MB of download speed)
TCP Ports 80 (HTTP), 443 (SSL) and 1935 (RTMP video streaming) enabled on the firewall
JavaScript and cookies enabled
Intel or AMD processor (1GHz or faster)
At least 512 MB RAM (at least 2 GB RAM for Vista)
Note: This service requires no client installation
```

VNC does not requires video streaming and can be used even on relatively narrow-band channels.